# How to implement Double tap for ipad in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

How to implement Double tap for ipad to selecting the text from text field in angularjs

Comment: The angular.touch API supports only swipe and click. You can implement your own double tap directive :)

Comment: I am new in angular, so can you give me some idea how i can implement own double tap directive.